# clicking on "Post your question" does not do anything

Tags: support

I am trying to post a question to stackoverflow. But the question is not getting submitted when i click "Post your question".

The title is : How should I pre-compile asp.net MVC web site in TFS 2010 build server

Question is :

"Hi,

I have set up continuous deployment process for asp.net MVC project using TFS 2010 build server. I am using “FlieCopy” to copy web site contents to shared path. Following are my MSBuild Arguments:

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir=\sharedPath  /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false

Now I want to pre-compile the site before copying it to shared path. With web-deploy there is an option to opt for pre-compiled binaries. On similar lines, can I instruct build server to pre-compile the site and then copy it to the shared path? If yes, which parameter will I need to add in the MSBuild argument?

Thanks
Amey "

When i click on the "Post your question". the page reloads but the question is not submitted.

Can somebody let me know what's happening.

Comment: Is there any error message showing up?

Comment: Hmm, I can imagine this question throwing up a few quality filter issues. But the message should be fairly obvious unless something has gone wrong in showing it to you

Comment: Incidently if it is a quality filter issue; it may be the code not formatted as code, select it and use the { } button. Or it may be the "Hi," and "Thanks Amey": we like the question to just have the question, nothing else

Comment: Did you remember to add tags?

Comment: [It looks like you managed to post your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269815/pre-compile-asp-net-mvc-web-site-in-tfs-2010-build-server)

Answer (score 3):

I got it. I am using IE-9. seems currently you can not post a question using IE-9. I tried with Firefox and it worked.

Comment: If this is the case this is a significant bug!

Comment: Indeed, according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) IE 9 is supported.

Comment: I know compatibility mode can be problematic at times... where you in compatibility mode?